# Homebrew fails to upgrade php to 7.4 (fails to install openssl 1.1) High Sierra

Tags: php, openssl, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade my php from 7.1 to 7.4 in my Mac with High Sierra (10.13.6) using homebrew. So I run:

```
brew install php@7.4
```

but it gets stuck at:

```
==> Installing php@7.4 dependency: openssl@1.1
==> perl ./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k --openssldir=
==> make
==> make install MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/share/man MANSUFFIX
==> make test
```

If I try to install the openssl package it fails too. It's that package that is causing the issue because i can install any other package with brew without issues.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I gave up and upgraded the OS to 10.15. Now I am able to upgrade to PHP 7.4 without problems.

Answer (score 0):

High Sierra is not in the Homebrew support list([Homebrew 2.6 release notes](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/)). Currently, Homebrew only supports Mojave, Catalina, Big Sur. So upgrading the macOS is a good call.